# Inserting values in a Trie

Tags: sml

I found this implementation of a Trie in an SML directory:

```
    signature DICT =
    sig
      type key = string                 (* concrete type *)
      type 'a entry = key * 'a          (* concrete type *)

      type 'a dict                      (* abstract type *)

      val empty : 'a dict
      val lookup : 'a dict -> key -> 'a option
      val insert : 'a dict * 'a entry -> 'a dict
      val toString : ('a -> string) -> 'a dict -> string
    end;  (* signature DICT *)

    exception InvariantViolationException

    structure Trie :> DICT = 
    struct
      type key = string
      type 'a entry = key * 'a

      datatype 'a trie = 
        Root of 'a option * 'a trie list
      | Node of 'a option * char * 'a trie list

type 'a dict = 'a trie

  val empty = Root(NONE, nil)

  (* val lookup: 'a dict -> key -> 'a option *)
  fun lookup trie key =
    let
      (* val lookupList: 'a trie list * char list -> 'a option *)
      fun lookupList (nil, _) = NONE
        | lookupList (_, nil) = raise InvariantViolationException
        | lookupList ((trie as Node(_, letter', _))::lst, key as letter::rest) =
            if letter = letter' then lookup' (trie, rest)
            else lookupList (lst, key)
        | lookupList (_, _) =
            raise InvariantViolationException

      (*
        val lookup': 'a trie -> char list
      *)
      and lookup' (Root(elem, _), nil) = elem
        | lookup' (Root(_, lst), key) = lookupList (lst, key)
        | lookup' (Node(elem, _, _), nil) = elem
        | lookup' (Node(elem, letter, lst), key) = lookupList (lst, key)
    in
      lookup' (trie, explode key)
    end

  (*
    val insert: 'a dict * 'a entry -> 'a dict
  *)
  fun insert (trie, (key, value)) = 
    let
      (*
        val insertChild: 'a trie list * key * value -> 'a trie list
        Searches a list of tries to insert the value. If a matching letter 
        prefix is found, it peels of a letter from the key and calls insert'. 
        If no matching letter prefix is found, a new trie is added to the list.
        Invariants:
          * key is never nil.
          * The trie list does not contain a Root.
        Effects: none
      *)
      fun insertChild (nil, letter::nil, value) = 
            [ Node(SOME(value), letter, nil) ]
        | insertChild (nil, letter::rest, value) = 
            [ Node(NONE, letter, insertChild (nil, rest, value)) ]
        | insertChild ((trie as Node(_, letter', _))::lst, key as letter::rest, value) = 
            if letter = letter' then
              insert' (trie, rest, value) :: lst
            else
              trie :: insertChild (lst, key, value)
        | insertChild (Root(_,_)::lst, letter::rest, value) =
            raise InvariantViolationException
        | insertChild (_, nil, _) = (* invariant: key is never nil *)
            raise InvariantViolationException

      (*
        val insert': 'a trie * char list * 'a -> 'a trie
        Invariants:
          * The value is on the current branch, including potentially the current node we're on.
          * If the key is nil, assumes the current node is the destination.
        Effects: none
      *)
      and insert' (Root(_, lst), nil, value) = Root(SOME(value), lst)
        | insert' (Root(elem, lst), key, value) = Root(elem, insertChild (lst, key, value))
        | insert' (Node(_, letter, lst), nil, value) = Node(SOME(value), letter, lst)
        | insert' (Node(elem, letter, lst), key, value) = Node(elem, letter, insertChild (lst, key, value))
    in
      insert'(trie, explode key, value)
    end

    (*
      val toString: ('a -> string) -> 'a dict -> string
    *)
    fun toString f trie =
      let
        val prefix = "digraph trie {\nnode [shape = circle];\n"
        val suffix = "}\n"

        (* val childNodeLetters: 'a trie list * char list -> char list *)
        fun childNodeLetters (lst, id) =
          (foldr 
            (fn (Node(_, letter, _), acc) => letter::acc
              | _ => raise InvariantViolationException) nil lst)

        (* val edgeStmt: string * string * char -> string *)
        fun edgeStmt (start, dest, lbl) =
          start ^ " -> " ^ dest ^ " [ label = " ^ Char.toString(lbl) ^ " ];\n"

        (* val allEdgesFrom: char list * char list *)
        fun allEdgesFrom (start, lst) = 
          (foldr 
            (fn (letter, acc) => 
              acc ^ edgeStmt(implode(start), implode(start @ [letter]), letter))
            "" lst)

        (* val labelNode: stirng * string -> string *)
        fun labelNode (id: string, lbl: string) =
          id ^ " [ label = \"" ^ lbl ^ "\" ];\n"

        fun toString' (Root(elem, lst), id) =
              let
                val idStr = implode(id)
                val childLetters = childNodeLetters(lst, id)
                val childStr = foldr (fn (trie, acc) => acc ^ toString'(trie, id)) "" lst
              in
                (case elem
                  of SOME(value) => 
                      labelNode (idStr, f(value)) ^ 
                      allEdgesFrom (id, childLetters)
                   | NONE => 
                      labelNode (idStr, "") ^ 
                      allEdgesFrom (id, childLetters)) ^ childStr
              end
          | toString' (Node(elem, letter, lst), id) =
              let
                val thisId = id @ [letter]
                val idStr = implode(thisId)
                val childLetters = childNodeLetters(lst, thisId)
                val childStr = foldr (fn (trie, acc) => acc ^ toString'(trie, thisId)) "" lst
              in
                (case elem
                  of SOME(value) => 
                      labelNode (idStr, f(value)) ^ 
                      allEdgesFrom (thisId, childLetters)
                   | NONE => 
                      labelNode (idStr, "") ^ 
                      allEdgesFrom (thisId, childLetters)) ^ childStr
              end
      in
        prefix ^ (toString' (trie, [#"_", #"R"])) ^ suffix
      end
end
```

Whenever i Try to insert or lookup for a string in this implementation using the above functions:insert,lookup i get these error:

```
stdIn:1.2-1.8 Error: unbound variable or constructor: lookup
stdIn:1.2-1.8 Error: unbound variable or constructor: insert
```

I think this is a declaration problem but i am not sure how to fix it.
Why is this happening and how can i insert or search properly in a Trie data structure?

Comment: I've voted to close this question since you indicate that you found this code, but didn't attribute it, and since the source of your problems is code that hasn't been posted.

Comment: You left out the details of how you're trying to use it. (I suspect that you might want to read the chapter on structures in your favourite SML book.)

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you don't have the intellectual rights to this code, you should link to where you found it rather than repeat it, since you provide no attributions. Secondly, the code seems to work fine. Here I'm inserting a couple of keys and looking them up:

```ml
$ sml trie.sml 
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.79 [built: Tue Aug  8 23:21:20 2017]
[opening trie.sml]
signature DICT =
  sig
    type key = string
    type 'a entry = key * 'a
    type 'a dict
    val empty : 'a dict
    val lookup : 'a dict -> key -> 'a option
    val insert : 'a dict * 'a entry -> 'a dict
    val toString : ('a -> string) -> 'a dict -> string
  end
[autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/basis.cm is stable]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/(basis.cm):basis-common.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
exception InvariantViolationException
structure Trie : DICT
- val foo = Trie.insert (Trie.empty, ("foo", 42));
val foo = - : int Trie.dict
- val bar = Trie.insert (foo, ("fab", 43));
val bar = - : int Trie.dict
- Trie.lookup bar "foo";
val it = SOME 42 : int option
- Trie.lookup bar "fab";
val it = SOME 43 : int option
- Trie.lookup bar "wat";
val it = NONE : int option
```